# Cannot acess my own Username directory

Tags: command-line, umount

My directory root is: `$home/pk`

The problem is that I'm unable to enter into home directory. When I type commend `cd /pk`, it gives an error, saying `file or directory not found`. When i type `-ls` command on terminal, it shows pk directory.

How can I access my home directory?

Answer (score 2):

To enter in your home folder, just type `cd` without parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run the full path:

```
cd /home/pk/
```

Mostly, your home directory is located inside `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run,

```
cd pk
```

not,

```
cd /pk
```

`cd /pk` searches for `pk` directory inside `/`.

Comment: Will only work from /home.

Comment: @guntbert leave the others except "it gives an error, saying file or directory not found. When i type -ls command on terminal, it shows pk".On running ls command it displays pk.So pk directory is in current path.

Comment: from that how `cd /home/pk` work?

Comment: Ack, I overlooked that part. But still your answer as of now works only in a rather special situation.